# What's the difference between the ways to say "try", 시도하다, 노력하다, 하려고 하다, and 해 보다?

Tags: grammar, vocabulary

There's some confusion between different ways to say "try":

- 시도하다
- 노력하다
- ~려고 하다
- ~어/아 보다

Are they used differently, or are the interchangeable?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They are not all interchangeable, and have somewhat different meanings.

- 시도하다

  - A verb meaning, "to attempt [something]"
  - It's typically used more in writing or formal situations, and in speech is not super common.

    > "He attempted suicide" ("He tried to kill himself.") => 자살을 시도했어요
- 노력하다

  - A verb with the meaning of "To exert effort." It is often used in phrases that translate to the English verb "try."

    > "I tried, but it didn't work out" => 노력했는데 안 됐어요.
- ~려고 하다 (하려고 하다, 먹으려고 하다, etc)

  - A grammar form meaning, vaguely, "with intent to..."
  - Often used when, in English, we would say "I tried to do [x]"

    > "He tried to kill me!" => 저를 죽이려고 했어요!
- ~아/어 보다 (해 보다, 먹어 보다, etc)

  - A grammar form that typically implies trying something to see what happens, to get the experience.

    > "Have you tried (eating) Kimchi?" => 김치 먹어 봤어요?

Comment: Could you add 노력하다 to the list?

Comment: @파울울 ah good call, edited into the answer.

Answer (score 1):

- 시도하다 : 試圖 + 하다, more formal version of '아/어 보다'.
- ~아/어 보다 : literal meaning is "see(보다) what happen". I don't think this phrase implies trying or planning.
- ~려고 하다 : interchangeable with "~할 계획이다". Meaning one has a plan, intentions, or a goal.

c.f. "노력하다" is most popular (and almost exact counterpart) word for "trying (with effort)".

Comment: 하려고 하다 is only interchangeable with 할 계획이다 in limited contexts, certainly not in general.

Comment: @dotVezz Maybe you are right, but I can't imagine a counter example right now...

Comment: One good example is something like "He tried to kill me!" 저를 죽이려고 했어요! If you changed that to 저를 죽일 계획이었어요 then it changes the meaning *greatly* and without any context, it implies that *no action was taken* - he planned to kill me, but changed his mind - while ~려고 했어요 implies that *action was taken*.

Comment: @dotVezz I understand your point. By the way, one can rewrite 죽이려고 했어요 to 죽일 계획이었다고 생각한다, change of tone and formalism(?).